# cantor diagonal argument for even numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

"Subset of countable set is countable", keeping this fact aside for a moment, consider even numbers.

let $A$ be the set of all even numbers and E be a countable subset of $A$, and similar to cantor's diagonal process, one can form a even number by writing the elements of $E$ continuously.

and since this number will not be an element of $E$, one can form a new even number every time. every countable subset of $A$ becomes proper subset of $A$. by this argument even numbers form an uncountable set correct?

But i know even numbers are not uncountable due to bijection from even numbers to natural numbers

What is wrong here?

Comment: How exactly do you go about this diagonal process? An even number is finite 'in both directions' (before/after the decimal point).

Comment: Even numbers don't have infinitely many digits.  What exactly are doing with these even numbers to get a new one?  That is not at all clear in your argument.

Comment: If E is infinite then writing the elements of E results in an infinite string.  That is not an even number.  But you can use this to prove the even numbers are infinite.

Comment: " and since this number" it's not a number " will not be an element of E" that's because it's not a number, " one can form a new even number" it's not a number " every time." Only if E is finite.  Then you have successfully proven the even numbers are not finite.

Comment: i start writing even number sequences 2,10,2164,.... i can write a new even number using the all the previous even numbers, 2102164. this even number appears nowhere in the sequence before and does it matter to have infinite digits in cantor adigonal argument? all one does is get a number which is not in the sequence. correct?

Comment: But that just shows it doesn't appear *before*.  It certainly can appear later.  If E is all evens, you get the number 2468101214.  That number *does* appear in E.

Comment: one doesnt prove that in cantor argument, i mean reapperance of a number in the sequence.

Comment: please help me out. I have this doubt since a long time

Comment: The Cantor argument takes something from *every* element in E to create the new real number.  If you take something from every element it has infinite representation.  An *integer* does not have infinite representation.  What you get is not an integer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59156/discussion-between-jnyan-and-fleablood).

Comment: @fleablood why cant i have infininite representation of even number for example i can represent 2 by 0000.....2 appending 0 many times in front

Comment: "why cant i have infininite representation of even number for example i can represent 2 by 0000.....2 appending 0 many times in front" An infinite number of zeros before is negligible becuase it is adding an infinite number of zeros.  But this is the *only* way we can "represent" an integer with infinite digits. We can't have an infinite number of any other digit and we can't have any infinite number of zeros *after* any digit. Anyway that is not important.  This procedure creates an infinite sum with an infinite number of non-zero digits and that is not resolvable. It doesn't make an integer.

Comment: Okay, I reread the argument.  to get $00000000.....02$ means you must have an infinitely countable list of even numbers of which all of them but one or only zeros, and the one that *isn't* only zeros must be the *last* in the list.  But if the list is countably infinite you *can't* have a last term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize two answer is bad form but:

Let's go over Cantor's diagonal argument in detail and your argument in detail.

First we must define what we think a real number and an even number is.

**Cantor:** A real number between $0$ and $1$  is a value $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_i*10^{-i}; a_i\in \mathbb N_{10}=\{0...9\}$.  There is a bijection from $j:[0,1] \leftarrow\rightarrow X =$ {the set of infinite sequences of $\mathbb N_{10}$} via $j(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_i*10^{-i}) = \{a_i\}$.

We are going to do our Cantor diagonal argument on $X = \{\text{infinite sequences of } \mathbb N_{10}\}$ rather than on $[0,1]$ but that will be fine as $[0,1] \approx X$.

**Your:**  An even integer is a value $\sum_{k=0}^na_k*10^k; a_i \in \mathbb N_{10}; a_0 \in \{0,2,4,6,8\}$.  There is a bijection $h: \{\text{even integers}\} \leftarrow \rightarrow Y = \{\text{finite sequences of }\mathbb N_{10}\text{ with first term even}\}$ via $h(\sum_{k=0}^na_k*10^k) = \{a_i\}$.

We will do our Cantor argument on $Y$ rather than the set of even integers but this is fine because $Y$ and the set of even integers or equivalent.

But ***NOTE***:  $X$ is a set of *infinite* sequences and $Y$ is a set of *finite* sequences.  That is going to make *all* the difference.

**Cantor**: Let $E$ be a countable infinite subset of $X$.  That is $E = \{v_i| v_i = \{a_{i,1}, a_{i,2},......\}\}$.

**Your**: Let $F$ be a countable infinite subset of $Y$. That is $F = \{w_i|w_i = \{a_{i,0}, a_{i,1} ....... a_{i, m}\}\}$

**Cantor**: We are going to find an $f: \{\text{countable infinite subsets of } X\} \rightarrow X$.  so that $f(E) \in X$ but $f(E) \not \in E \subset X$.

Thus no countable subset of $X$ is all of $X$ and thus $X$ is uncountable.

**Your**: We are going to attempt (but ultimately fail) to find a $g: \{\text{countable infinite subsets of }Y\}\rightarrow  Y$.  What we are going to define *instead* is a $g:\{\text{countable infinite subsets of }Y\}\rightarrow X$.  We will fail to show that $f(F) \in Y$.  We will find instead that $f(F) \not \in Y$. (Although $f(F) \in X$).

As $f:\{\text{countable infinite subsets of}Y\}\not\rightarrow  Y$ the fact that $f(F) \not \in F$ does not demonstrate anything.

**Cantor:** Let $f(E) = \{b_i\}$ so that $b_i = a_{i,i} + 1 \mod 10$ we $\{a_{i,k} = v_i \in E$.  Thus $\{b_i\}$ is an infinite sequence and thus in $X$.  So $f: \{\text{countable infinite subsets of } X\}\rightarrow  X$. And $b_i \ne a_{i,i}$ for any $i$, $\{b_i\} \ne v_i$ for any $v_i \in E$ so $f(E) \not \in E$.

We are done.

**Your:** Let $g(F) = \{b_i\}$ were $b_{(\sum_{i=0}^k i)+j} = a_{k+1, j}$; that is ... we simply write every sequence one after another.

However as $F$ is an infinite set this $g(F)$ is an infinite sequence.  $Y$ is a set of ***finite*** sequences.  So $g: \{\text{countable infinite subsets of }Y\}\not \rightarrow  Y$.  Instead $g: \{\text{countable infinite subsets of }Y\}\rightarrow  X$.  So $g(F) \not \in Y$.  As $g(F) \not \in Y$, the fact that $g(F) \not \in F \subset Y$ is not useful.

Comment: Thank you for all the effort.

Comment: I got some more insight myself, coming up with new even number works fine, but I should be able to do that even after countably infinite times. Which is possible only if the number which I am trying to form has infinite digits. This is where infinite digits come in to picture and after infinite times, I can't get an even number the way I could after finite times.

Comment: exactly.  What you get is not an integer as it has infinite digits.  The closest you can claim is that $a = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i*10^i$ which diverges and is not a meaningful value and is *not* an even integer.

Answer (score 1):

> similar to cantor's diagonal process, one can form a even number by writing the elements of $E$ continuously

This is mistaken. For simplicity, let $E$ be the positive even numbers. The notation $2468101214161820\ldots$ doesn't name a number. Nor does $\ldots2018161412108642$. The decimal notation $0.2468101214161820\ldots$ does name a real number, but it's not an integer, let alone an even integer.

Comment: given any even number sequence, say, 10,14,216,....i can form an even number, an integer, 1014216, and this even number is nowhere in the sequence, correct?

Comment: That's a finite sequence.  So that proves the evens are not finite.

Comment: it also proves that every subset of E is proper subset of E, meaning E is uncountable.

Comment: " given any even number sequence, say, 10,14,216,....i can form an even number, an integer, 1014216, and this even number is nowhere in the sequence, correct?" Incorrect, why wouldn't 1014216 appear later in the sequences?  You need some way to guarantee that the even number formed by some of terms never appears later.  The Cantor way of doing that is to take some ing from every term.  But that results in something infinite that is not a number at all.

Comment: by that logic, whatever number is obtained,in cantor argument,  which is not in the sequence till then, could also be somewhere in the sequence later

Comment: It only proves that if E is finite.  If E is infinite it proves nothing of the sort.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59155/discussion-between-jnyan-and-fleablood).

Comment: The Cantor argument is that you take a digit from every element,* all* of them.  Your argument is you create a new number from *all* the even numbers in E.  If E is infinite the result will be an infinite string.  That is NOT an integer.

Comment: If you stopped doing the Cantor diagonal after only a finite number of term, that would be true.  But in the Cantor diagonal you must do it for *every* term.  If you copied *all* the even numbers what you get simply is not an integer at all. That's the difference and it is essential.  A real number can have infinite decimals.  Therefore there are $2^{N} $ of them.  That's uncountable.  An integer can not have infinite digits.  So there only $\sum N=N^2$ of them, that's countable.  You method creates something that is NOT an integer.

Answer (score 1):

If E is finite, the result will be an even number not in E.  Ergo There are  infinite even numbers.

That's fine and valid.

If E is infinite the result is an infinite string of digits.  That is not a number at all.  Nothing relevant can be concluded.